# Titlesec command blocked by frontmatter

Tags: formatting, chapters, titlesec, front-matter

\frontmatter blocks the propagation of the \titleformat from the preface to the first chapter. Is there a way to avoid that ?

```
  \documentclass[11pt,A4]{book}
  \usepackage{titlesec}

  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries}{Title Above}{20pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule\vspace{0.2ex}\titlerule]

  \begin{document}
  \chapter{Preface (before frontmatter)}
  \frontmatter% blocks the propagation of the titleformat to the first chapter
  \chapter{Chapter 1 (after frontmatter)}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

The upper title of Chapter 1 is shown only if \frontmatter is absent.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Chapters in `\frontmatter` are really `\chapter*`, so your "Title above" definition won't apply there. Depending on what you want to achieve, you can add   `\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\bfseries}{Title Above}{20pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule\vspace{0.2ex}\titlerule]`

Comment: And I'd use `\mainmatter` for the main body of the document (which puts the chapter titles back to normal). Not sure if Chapter 1 is supposed to be in the main matter or the front matter.

Comment: But if anything is supposed to be in `\frontmatter`, surely the preface should be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected code, thanks to all the comments above.

```
  \documentclass[11pt,A4]{book}
  \usepackage{titlesec}

  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{Title Above}{20pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule\vspace{0.2ex}\titlerule]

  \begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \chapter{Preface (after frontmatter)}
  \mainmatter
  \chapter{Chapter 1 (with ``mainmatter")}
  \backmatter
  \chapter{Chapter after ``backmatter")}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]